# Android Redraw or Refresh a single row in listview in baseAdapter when click on itme in the row

Tags: android, android-listview

This is a listview that uses a baseAdapter to get the data, I want to click on play button to hide it and show the pause button instead of it and versa, I added onClickListener to the play button in the baseAdapter in method getView() and try to hide it and show the pause button but nothing worked...!!?? the result is always hide and show the buttons in the next row of listview and sometimes not...?? I added the method notifyDataSetChanged() in the clickListener in the baseAdapter and in the Activity but also didn't work.....!!? plz plz plz help me I have been stuck with this for 2 days.
Here is my code for Activity class and Adapter class.

```
public class AudioBookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private BookIndex bookIndex;
private ViewHolder holder;
private int selectedPosition = -1;
private MediaPlayer mediaFileTrack = new MediaPlayer();

public AudioBookAdapter(Context context, BookIndex bookIndex) {
    this.context = context;
    this.bookIndex = bookIndex;
}

/**
 * @return the audioFileTrack
 */
public MediaPlayer getMediaFileTrack() {
    return mediaFileTrack;
}

/**
 * @param audioFileTrack the audioFileTrack to set
 */
public void setMediaFileTrack(MediaPlayer mediaFileTrack) {
    this.mediaFileTrack = mediaFileTrack;
}

/**
 * @return the context
 */
public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

/**
 * @param context the context to set
 */
public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * @return the bookIndex
 */
public BookIndex getBookIndex() {
    return bookIndex;
}

/**
 * @param bookIndex the bookIndex to set
 */
public void setBookIndex(BookIndex bookIndex) {
    this.bookIndex = bookIndex;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return getBookIndex().getBookIndexes().size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return getBookIndex().getBookIndexes().get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_track_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtAudioFileTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAudioFileTitle);
        holder.imgSelectedAudioFile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgSelected);
        holder.imgUnselectedAudioFile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgUnselected);
        holder.flUnselectedTrack = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flUnselectedTrack);
        holder.flSelectedTrack = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flSelectedTrack);
        holder.audioSeekBar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.audioSeekBar);
        holder.btnPause = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPausePaly);
        holder.btnNext = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtAudioFileTitle.setText(getBookIndex().getBookIndexes().get(position));

    if (getSelectedPosition() == position) {
        Log.i("JML...Info", "Position in Adapter = " + position);
        holder.flSelectedTrack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.flUnselectedTrack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnPause.setSelected(true);
        holder.btnPause.setFocusable(true);
        holder.btnPause.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    } else {
        Log.i("JML...Info", "Else Position in Adapter = " + position);
        holder.flUnselectedTrack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.flSelectedTrack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (getSelectedPosition() == position) {
                // getMediaFileTrack().pause();

                holder.btnPause.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_play));

                Log.i("JML...Info", "Pause + Position = " + getSelectedPosition());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param holder
 */
protected void playTrack(ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.flUnselectedTrack.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

/**
 * 
 * @author Jamil
 * 
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtAudioFileTitle;
    ImageView imgSelectedAudioFile;
    ImageView imgUnselectedAudioFile;
    FrameLayout flUnselectedTrack;
    FrameLayout flSelectedTrack;
    SeekBar audioSeekBar;
    ImageButton btnPause;
    ImageButton btnNext;

}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return selectedPosition;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param position
 */
public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Activity class

```
/**
```

* 
 */

```
public class DisplayAudioBook extends CustomeActivity {

    private Bundle bundle;
    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    private ListView listView = null;
    private MaktabatiHelper maktabatiHelper;
    private MediaPlayer mediaFileTrack;
    private SeekBar audioSeekBar;
    private Handler handlerSeekBar = new Handler();
    private AudioBookAdapter audioBookAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_audio_book);
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAudioBookFiles);

        if (!isBookFilesUnzip(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID"))) {
            new UnzipAudioFileTask().execute(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID"));
        }
        audioBookAdapter = new AudioBookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getBookIndex(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID")));
        listView.setAdapter(audioBookAdapter);
        listView.setDivider(null);
        listView.setDividerHeight(0);
        audioBookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                audioBookAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
                View oldView = adapter.getChildAt(audioBookAdapter.getSelectedPosition());
                FrameLayout rowOfList;
                if (oldView != null && audioBookAdapter.getSelectedPosition() != -1) {
                    rowOfList = (FrameLayout) oldView.findViewById(R.id.flUnselectedTrack);
                    rowOfList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                rowOfList = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.flSelectedTrack);
                rowOfList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                listView.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
                listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        audioBookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param bookId
     */
    private boolean isBookFilesUnzip(String bookId) {
        boolean isExits = false;
        File file = new File(Constants.AUDIO_EBOOKS_UNZIP_FILES_DIRECTORY + "/" + bookId);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            maktabatiHelper = new MaktabatiHelper(getApplicationContext());
            int indexCount = maktabatiHelper.lstBookIndex(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID"));
            File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
            if (indexCount != listFiles.length - 1) {
                Toast.makeText(DisplayAudioBook.this.getApplicationContext(), "Misssssssssing audio file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            isExits = true;
        } else {
            new UnzipAudioFileTask().execute(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID"));
            isExits = true;
        }
        return isExits;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private BookIndex getBookIndex(String BookId) {
        maktabatiHelper = new MaktabatiHelper(getApplicationContext());
        BookIndex bookIndex = maktabatiHelper.getBookIndex(bundle.getString("BOOK_ID"));
        return bookIndex;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @author Jamil
     * 
     */
    private class UnzipAudioFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loadingDialog = new RightJustifyDialog(DisplayAudioBook.this);
            loadingDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading));
            loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.waiting));
            loadingDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Utils.unzipFile(Constants.AUDIO_EBOOKS_UNZIP_FILES_DIRECTORY, params[0] + ".zip");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return params[0];

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            AudioBookAdapter audioBookAdapter = new AudioBookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getBookIndex(result));
            listView.setDivider(null);
            listView.setDividerHeight(0);
            listView.setAdapter(audioBookAdapter);
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // mediaFileTrack.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android reuses your views, especially with ViewHolder. I implemented successfully a similar list as yours without ViewHolder. You should try to make the list without ViewHolder and see if it works.